# difference between ui-hidden-accessible and ui-hide-label

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm newbie to jquery. i have a doubt regarding the above question. Even in their official document it was not cleared. That is they didn't provide the additional information about the accessible and hide label. Any other suggestion [Resources link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/docs-forms.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A major difference that i see is that ui-hide-label is applied to the container elements within which labels are present to hide all labels. By applying ui-hidden-accessible though to individual labels, you can control which ones to hide. Thats what the document states too.  both make label visible to assistive technologies though.

Comment: @ umair Khan nice response. Good u clarified my doubt .